# Array C pass by reference

Tags: c

How do I pass an array as a function parameter by reference so I can allocate memory for it and then have it returned. I am already returning anothe rarray with the routine.

```
int main(){
float * array_in = NULL;
float * data = Fill_Array(&array_in);
return 0;
}

float * Fill_Array(float * array)
{
    array    = malloc(sizeof(float*));
    *array[1] = 10;

    float * return_array = malloc(sizeof(float*));

    return return_array;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void
Fill_Array (float **pArray)
{
  *pArray = malloc (sizeof (float) * 100);      /* 100 = number of items */

  (*pArray)[0] = 1.0;
  (*pArray)[1] = 2.0;
  return;
}

int
main ()
{
  float *array_in = NULL;
  Fill_Array (&array_in);
  /* do something here */
  free (array_in);
  return 0;
}
```

Arrays are always passed by reference in the sense you pass a pointer, rather than a thick copy. If you want to do an allocation in the function, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Worked flawlessly thank you! And my apologies for being unclear. Wrote it in a hurry! Thanks a ton guys

Comment: @abligh Consider this allocation style `*pArray = malloc(100 * sizeof *(*pArray));`  IMO, easier to code, check and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

This code is messed up. I'm not sure what to start.

First off, you can pass an array like this:

```
Fill_Array(array_in);
```

But this code won't work. For starters, the first thing `Fill_Array` does is throw the value away by overwriting the variable with a newly allocated block of memory.

Second, you are only allocated enough memory or a pointer to a float. It is not safe to write floats to the memory returne.

And finally, you then call `malloc()` a second time. Where is any of this memory getting freed by calling `free()`? This is causing memory leaks.

You need to better define what you are trying to do, and then start again.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant. This one is free from memory leaks.

You can create any number of arrays of any dimensions. 
Just do not forget to work in pairs "Create-Destroy"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float *CreateArray (int N)
{
  float *arr = malloc (sizeof (float) * N);      

  for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    arr[i] = 0.0f;

  return arr;
}

void DestroyArray (float *arr)
{
  free(arr);    
}

int main ()
{
  int N = 10;   /* number of items you need this time*/
  float *arr = CreateArray (N);
    //...do something

  DestroyArray (arr);

  //.......
  return 0;
}
```